# how to check today and uncheck previous day in pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check today's date and uncheck the last available date in a pivot table using VBA(excludes Sat & Sun).

I am nooob in VBA so I have tried recording a macro and did some changes 
pivot tables may be different and passing some variables which have those dates to Check and un-check.

```vb
Sheets("A Chart").PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotCache.Refresh
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Added Date")
  .PivotItems("$inbound_previousday$").Visible = False
  .PivotItems("$today$").Visible = True
   Sheets("B Chart").PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotCache.Refresh
   ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Added Date")
     .PivotItems("$outbound_Previousday").Visible = False
     .PivotItems("$today$").Visible = True
   End With

End With
```

Is there any possible way to check today's date and uncheck the first most available date in the drop down.

[image]

Comment: In your example, there are 27 days between the date being added and the date being removed. Is it always 27 days? Also, is "today's" date always actually today, or is it determined some other way?

Comment: yes, those are constant values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Sub FilterDays()

    Dim NumDaysSelected As Long
    Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    NumDaysSelected = 27 'Change this number to select the amount of days selected
    StartDate = Date - NumDaysSelected
    EndDate = Date

    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8")
        pt.PivotFields("Added Date").ClearAllFilters 'This line is needed to clear existing filter before applying new one
        pt.PivotFields("Added Date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, _
            Value1:=StartDate, Value2:=EndDate

    End Sub
```

Comment: The above is selecting every available date and then going back to the start where it began. i.e., dates are same as before

Comment: Do you have any other code mixed in there?  The `.ClearFilters` will make it so everything is selected, `.PivotFilters.Add` will filter it to the range you want with Value1 & Value 2

Answer (score 0):

Since your values are constant, this is the simplest. `Date` here returns today.

```
With Sheets("A Chart").PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Added Date")
    .PivotItems(Date - 27).Visible = False
    .PivotItems(Date).Visible = True
End With
```

Comment: when i use above cod to run on my excel it gives me error "Unable to get the pivot items property of the pivot field class" - the pivotfeild is "AddedDate" only

Comment: One last suggestion, how can i exclude sat and Sunday from the code

Comment: When you say exclude, do you mean you want them unchecked in the filter as well?